# return Class.forName instead of new instance

Tags: java, reflection, factory

I've found this code inside an old project

```
public abstract class AireBatchDaoFactory {
     public static final String ORACLE_FACTORY = "airebatch.oracle.OracleDaoFactory";
     public static AireBatchDaoFactory getFactory(String factory) throws SQLException
     {
        try {
           return (AireBatchDaoFactory) Class.forName(factory).newInstance();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("error msg");
        }
     }
     public abstract AireBatchDao getAireBatchDao() throws SQLException;}
```

I would like to understand the concrete difference beetween

```
return (AireBatchDaoFactory) Class.forName(factory).newInstance();
```

and

```
return new AireBatchDaoFactory();
```

Comment: It's called **reflection**. There is a `String` describing the FQCN of the `class` and the code tries to convert that `String` first into `Class` instance and then into a new instance of that `class` assuming a default constructor.  This is the **only** way of creating an instance from a `String` - `new` will obviously not work here.

Comment: writing just `return class.forName(factory).newInstance();` could have been generic, rest seems same. Also catching super `Exception` and throwing `SQLException` instead of `ClassNotFoundException`, maybe somebody would have changed this over a period of time. Even no use of variable `ORACLE_FACTORY`

Comment: Additionally, usually those factories are _abstract classes_ (like in your case also) that can't be instantiated. The cast is necessary to fulfill the method's signature (and could fail as well).

Comment: @ankur-singhal it's `public static final` - the intent is presumably that that is the default value passed into the API, The exception handling is pretty normal for JDBC code - rethrowing a `SQLException` makes the handling code consistent when using the JDBC API.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that `new AireBatchDaoFactory` will create an instance of *that specific class* (or not compile, if `AireBatchDaoFactory` is an interface or abstract class). But `factory` may contain the fully-qualified name of *any* class that implements `AireBatchDaoFactory` (if it's an interface) or subclasses it (if it's a class). `Class.forName(factory).newInstance()` will load the class named by `factory` and create a new instance of it.

This is quite a common pattern for runtime plugins to a codebase. Typically you define an interface which the plugins implement. Then you provide a runtime means of specifying what specific class to use (in a properties file, in some other config, etc.), and use `Class.forName` to load the class and `newInstance` to create an instance of it. Since the class is decided at *runtime*, it can be something that the authors of the code using it have never seen, written long after the code that uses it. Hence using it for plugins.

Consider:

`Plugin.java`:

```
interface Plugin {
    void doSomething();
}
```

`Foo.java`:

```
public class Foo implements Plugin {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm Foo");
    }
}
```

`Bar.java`:

```
public class Bar implements Plugin {
    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("I'm Bar");
    }
}
```

`App.java`:

```
public class App {

    public static final void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String classToLoad = args[0];
            Plugin plugin = Class.forName(classToLoad).newInstance();
            plugin.doSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            //...handle error...
        }
    }
}
```

Running

```
java App Foo
```

...loads the `Foo` class and calls `doSomething` on it, giving us `"I'm Foo"`.

Running

```
java App Bar
```

...loads the `Bar` class and calls `doSomething` on it, giving us `"I'm Bar"`.

Answer (score 2):

Look the method carefully

```
getFactory(String factory)
```

You are receiving class name as a parameter. You cannot write

```
factory factory = new factory(); // error.
```

Where

```
 Class.forName(factory).newInstance();
```

Is valid.

In short you are creating a Instance for a class using it's name which you don't at compile time and creating the instance at run time with passed name using Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `new AireBatchDaoFactory()` for an abstract class. In your example, reflection is used to get an instance of the class with the name, which is passed as a parametre of getFactory method. This class should extends an AireBatchDaoFactory abstract class.

In this case, you can change, which implementation of AireBatchDaoFactory you get from it on runtime. To know the reason, why it's made this way, you may take a look at how is this logic used.